# XPath - select all nodes which are only child of type

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xml-parsing, lxml

I have something like:

```
<fieldset>
    <field name='field1'></field>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <field name='field2'></field>
    <field name='field3'></field>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <field name='field4'></field>
    <text></text>
</fieldset>
```

I want to select all the `field` nodes which are only children on type `field`.

Ie. `field1` matches, and `field4` as well (the `text` node is not of type `field`).

I can't make it work using `sibling` and this neither:

`//fieldset/field[not(count(../field))>1]`

Comment: @alecxe has given you the answer, but the reason your current expression didn't work, is that you had a parenthesis in the wrong place. It should have been `//fieldset/field[not(count(../field)>1)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `//fieldset[count(field)=1]/field` xpath expression.

Demo using [`xmllint`](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html):

```
$ xmllint input.xml --xpath '//fieldset[count(field)=1]/field'
<field name="field1"/>
<field name="field4"/>
```